# Possible to Change TextBox Style When Input Changes? (Stylesheet/Macro?)

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, winforms

Is it possible to create a macro or stylesheet so that when a TextBox text area is empty, it is yellow per se and when it has data it is white. I would like to accomplish this without having to explicitly call the TextChanged event.

Comment: ASP.NET or Windows Forms?  You say Stylesheet, but just in case you don't mean Web...

Comment: Sorry Windows Forms, I was thinking something like a Stylesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a new Custom Control that extends the TextBox and does what you're seeking?  That way you can adjust it centrally as well.  It would certainly use the TextChanged event however.  Another way is to put the code in the form, but I think that would be much slower and not reusable.